# How to find the highest count of same values in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the count of the most common value in one of the columns. For example, my table looks like this:

```
id | item | color
________________________________________________________
1  | APPLE | RED
2  | PEAR  | GREEN
3  | APPLE | GREEN
4  | ORANGE| ORANGE
5  | APPLE | RED
6  | APPLE | YELLOW
7  | ORANGE| ORANGE
```

I want the result to show:

```
There are 4 counts of APPLE
```

Because there are 4 'APPLE's and only one 'PEAR' and two 'ORANGE's, only the highest count will show up.

Answer (score 4):

To get the result you've specified, you can specify a virtual field and use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to join the bits together like this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('There are ', COUNT(item), ' counts of ', item) as your_result
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY COUNT(item) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

> There are 4 counts of APPLE

---

**Note:**

Since you've tagged PHP in this question, it's probably a good idea to remember that databases store information, and your PHP code/HTML will present that data to the user. You should try and keep those layers separate whenever possible, meaning you shouldn't format them like this within the result but rather should just return the raw data (item name and count) from MySQL, then use PHP to present it.

In this case, you should use one of the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643529/2812842) here and simply output the formatted result using PHP:

```
// your query, example:
$result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo 'There are ' . $result['count'] . ' counts of ' . $result['item'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just order by the count, group by the item, and limit to 1 result:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(item) as count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY item 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```